# Why there is an extra space on the button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, button, imagebutton

I've been trying to figure it out, but I am giving it up after 4 hours of digging and staring at my code!.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Listening to DOM events</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html,body,#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.controls {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 240px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
</style>

<title>Places search box</title>


<script 

    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>

<script>

var map;
var marker;
var latLng;

function initialize() {

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(xxxx, -xxxxx);
      var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      navigationControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      scaleControl: true,
      center: myLatlng
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

}  //End of OnStart


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>

    <style>
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        width: 240px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #00ffec;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 240px;
      }

      #target {
        width: 240px;
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div> 
      <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder=""> 
      <input type="button" value="Clear" style="Float:right" style="width:60px; height:40px"
                                                                                onclick="Clear_SearchText()">    
    </div>  
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone please help me understand why there is an extra space taking over my layout space????

Thank you very much

Edit:  Re-uploaded better picture.

[image]

Comment: It is by the div that contains the textfield and button....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ny1jz245/1/

Comment: Yeah, maybe the question isn't clear but I don't understand the confusion. The input text field is creating the vertical space and the button is set to float right, which gives you the horizontal space. No mystery?

Comment: I used Paint software to remove the textbox (which is on the bottom of that extra space."  The extra space belongs to this button.  I edited my topic.  Thanks

Comment: You posted a question and manually edited your screenshot to hide the source of the problem? Oookay...

Answer (score 0):

The container `div` of the text `input` and button `input` will occupy that place.
Simplest would be to set the button `input` or `div` height to match. Example to make the button to match:

Add id to the button to reference it:

```
<input id="clearbutton" type="button" value="Clear" style="Float:right" style="width:60px; height:40px" onclick="Clear_SearchText()">
```

Set height in css:

```
<style>
#clearbutton {
    height: 32px;
}
</style>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/pqdtgmdp/1/

**EDIT**

So based on your complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Listening to DOM events</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html,body,#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.controls {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 240px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
</style>

<title>Places search box</title>


<script 

    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>

<script>

var map;
var marker;
var latLng;

function initialize() {

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(xxxx, -xxxxx);
      var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      navigationControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      scaleControl: true,
      center: myLatlng
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

}  //End of OnStart


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>

    <style>
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        width: 240px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #00ffec;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 240px;
      }

      #target {
        width: 240px;
      }

      #clearbutton, #pac-input{
        height: 32px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div> 
      <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder=""> 
      <input id="clearbutton" type="button" value="Clear" style="Float:right" style="width:60px; height:40px"
                                                                                onclick="Clear_SearchText()">    
    </div>  
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have no clue how to use css as I started learning about Javascript a few days ago.  I am using Eclipse to code Javascript code.  I am using this Javascript to create a map for my personal Android app.  Can you please show me how to put this in Javascript instead?  Maybe, can you please show me how to use css?  I very appreciate for your help.

Comment: I suspected you are new at these things, that's why I put the css code in `<style>` tags. You can simply copy it in your HTML code and it will work

Comment: Sorry, I went to bed for work today.  I've tried the code you mentioned above, but it is still the same as before.  What it's weird is that it looks fine (no extra space) when the app is opened, but then the extra space shows up and pushes down the searchBox after everything is loaded.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I removed the clearButton, this extra white space is gone totally.  Somehow there is a hidden layout/panel whenever this clearButton is added...

Comment: The problem is that the text input and the button are in the same div element, if their height is not the same, you get a white space to fill that gap up. I will edit the code again to set both height to the same value.

Comment: Try now. You can play with the values as well.

Comment: I just tried it, but it is the same as before.  Thanks a lot for helping